# Documents link in files is replaced

Tags: nautilus

In nautilus i.e., `files` the documents link in the side bar is replaced by some other link. What should I do?

**Note**:
I've removed my user name in the screenshot.[image]
The output of `ls -l ~` is:

```
total 684
-rw-rw----  1 sony sony   3039 Jul 18 11:28 add_user
drwx------  2 root root   4096 Jun 27 19:58 auth
drwxrwxr-x  3 sony sony   4096 Jun 10 18:37 conky-manager
drwxr-xr-x  2 sony sony   4096 Jul 29 16:24 Desktop
-rw-rw-r--  1 sony sony  97117 Jul 15 19:23 D-Link DSL-2730U.pdf
drwxr-xr-x  3 sony sony   4096 Aug  8 21:45 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 21 sony sony  16384 Aug  9 16:08 Downloads
-rw-rw-r--  1 sony sony  74325 Jul 12 09:38 DSL Router.pdf
drwxr-xr-x  2 sony sony   4096 May 23 00:15 dwhelper
drwxrwxr-x  3 sony sony   4096 May 14 05:51 Etoys
-rw-r--r--  1 sony sony   8980 Apr 19 03:31 examples.desktop
drwxrwxr-x  4 sony sony   4096 Jun  5 22:44 GTA San Andreas User Files
-rw-rw-r--  1 sony sony  78538 Jun 28 11:53 hardinfo_report.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 sony sony 137357 May 16 14:45 history.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      0 Jul 18 15:33 locate
-rw-rw-r--  1 sony sony 118781 May 25 10:24 mozilla.pdf
drwxr-xr-x  4 sony sony   4096 Aug  9 15:46 Music
-rw-rw-r--  1 sony sony    417 Jun 13 18:51 mwf_config
drwxrwxr-x  2 sony sony   4096 May 22 10:20 My Games
-rwxrwxr-x  1 sony sony  31684 Jul 15 22:41 openvas-check-setup
drwxrwxr-x  3 sony sony   4096 Jul 23 11:38 openvas-src
drwxr-xr-x 18 sony sony  28672 Aug  9 20:24 Pictures
lrwxrwxrwx  1 sony sony     36 May 22 03:47 PlayOnLinux's virtual drives -> /home/sony/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/
drwx------  2 root root   4096 Jun 27 19:58 plugins
drwxr-xr-x  2 sony sony   4096 May 24 17:02 Public
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Jun  7 11:30 RECOVERED_FILES
drwx------  2 sony sony   4096 Jul 19 11:46 scripts
drwxrwxr-x  2 sony sony   4096 May  6 17:38 softwares
drwxr-xr-x  2 sony sony   4096 Jun  4 14:33 SpringLobby
lrwxrwxrwx  1 sony sony     18 May 14 19:08 squeak -> /home/sony/.squeak
drwxr-xr-x  2 sony sony   4096 Apr 19 03:38 Templates
drwxr-xr-x  3 sony sony   4096 Jul  2 13:19 Videos
drwxrwxr-x  2 sony sony   4096 Jul 29 12:26 VirtualBox VMs
drwxrwxr-x  3 sony sony   4096 May 10 21:25 WebCam Media
```

The output of `cat .config/user-dirs.dirs` is:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l ~` and `cat .config/user-dirs.dirs`? Also, any idea what could've caused this? Did you change/configure anything recently that could cause this?

Comment: @Alaa Ali I've added the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe somehow the folder was somehow renamed.  Try to rename the folder, and see.

Here is what I did, just to reproduce the problem.  I right clicked on the documents folder, and renamed it `/home/xxxx/Downloads`.

[image]

Then did `cat .config/user-dirs.dirs` the output is below:

[image]

I then renamed the folder back to Documents, and did `cat .config/user-dirs.dirs`, and everything was back the way it was.

[image]
[image]